# How to check if the activity was started by wearable listener service?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am opening an activity in watch by clicking a button in mobile using wearable listener service. I can also launch the activity by clicking the app in watch. So I would like to differentiate them - I want to know when the activity was launched from phone so that the activity layout looks slightly different. What is the easiest way to do this? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start an activity through a WearableListenerService, you are the one who is setting up an intent and call startActivity. As such, you can set a certain boolean "extras" to true on the intent to be passed to the activity and then in the activity, extract that "extras" and based on the value, inflate different layouts; when your activity is started from the list of apps, that boolean "extras" will be false.

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks a lot..Just tried..it worked.. One doubt..How do I close or stop an activity in watch from mobile by clicking a button? What command should I use in wearable listener service class?Should I destroy it or pause it? What should be my approach? Please advise

Comment: You shouldn't use WearableListenerService to close a running activity; you would need to have your activity register a message listener when it starts (and remove the listener when it is stopped). Then in that listener, you can call finish() when the activity receives the appropriate message.